# TeamCity: Change parameter within same build step

Tags: batch-file, cmd, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I know that to change a parameter in a .cmd batch script, we can use: 
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='paramName' value='abcdef']"

But the change takes effect only in the next build step after this has been set in the previous build step. I want to set and change a parameter within the same build step. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: What kind of step is the build step?

Comment: The value is already available (otherwise it would be impossible to set parameter using service message), so why not just use it?

Comment: One reason you may wish to use it would be when you have some logic to define the parameter in your build step, and want to use that parameter in a plugin which extends the build step (e.g. using it in the upload spec in the Artifactory plugin).